# Prestashop - Add column with link to an order in backoffice

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to add a new column to a Admin Controller, but I want this column to be a link to a specific Order instead of just the ID. So far, I have this:

```
<?php

class AdminDnDPaymentsController extends  ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->table = 'dnd_payments';
        $this->className = 'DnDPayment';
        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_dnd_payments' => array('title' => $this->l('ID'), 'align' => 'center', 'width' => 25),
            'id_order' => array('title' => $this->l('Order'), 'align' => 'center', 'width' => 80),
            'bank' => array('title' => $this->l('Bank'), 'width' => 120),
            'payer' => array('title' => $this->l('Payer name'), 'width' => 140),
            'amount' => array('title' => $this->l('Amount'), 'width' => 80),
            'reference' => array('title' => $this->l('Reference'), 'width' => 120),
            'date_add' => array('title' => $this->l('Date add'), 'type' => 'date'),
        );
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        //$this->addRowAction('view');
        //$this->addRowAction('edit');
        $this->addRowAction('delete');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use callbacks for columns when you wish to alter its appearance.

```
$this->fields_list = array(
    'id_order' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Order'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => 80,
        'callback' => 'printOrderLink'
    ),
    // rest of the fields
);
```

Now create a method which will handle the appearance...

```
public function printOrderLink($value, $row)
{
    $link = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminOrders').'&id_order='.(int)$value.'&vieworder';

    return '<a href="'.$link.'">View order</a>';
}
```

So for every row on `id_order` column, the `printOrderLink` method will be called and a link to that order will be displayed instead of ID.

`$value` will be the current row's order ID and `$row` is an array which holds all column values for current row (useful if you need to modify column appearance based on another column value).